# How to communicate between java(PC) and android under the WIFI without using modems or access-points?

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi, communication

After searching a lot on the web I can not find obvious answer for my question.
I'm trying to send some messages using wifi between my PC and my android phone. My PC runs a java program and in this situation I have only two devices i.e a PC and an android phone. I want to make connection  between these two devices **without using modems or access-points**. I have very little experience about networking/communication and related stuff but I already know there are two kind of communication: client-server and P2P. I have no idea which one to use in this situation.

Usually code examples or tutorials are very good ways to learn something but any idea about how can I start will also be helpful :)

thanks a lot,Soroush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not very experienced in this area I'm going to suggest that you create a Client-Server solution.

The next step is to establish which end-point is going to act as the server. In most cases a mobile device would act as a client and your PC as the server, however it works both ways.

From here you should be able to find plenty of tutorials describing how to implement this kind of solution (I've done this many times myself when I first learned this).

**Examples:**

[What is a socket?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html) - A basic walkthrough of network communication in Java, with code examples.

[Java - Networking](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm) - Another fairly straight forward tutorial.

[Android Socket Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) - A more Androidy tutorial, much the same as the others.

Hope this gets you pointing in the right direction!

Comment: first thank a lot for your answer
and if i use socket i do not need any modem and 2 device (PC and phone) is enough for sending and receiving message ?

Comment: I just realised that I misread your post a little. But in any case, you should be able to just turn one of the devices in to a mobile hotspot (i.e. make it act as an access-point).

Comment: :)
for that purpose i have to use p2p ?

Comment: Well, in this case it would not make any difference. Your devices still need to be connected to either the same network or two different ones which are in turn connected to each other in some way (e.g. the internet) in order to communicate with each other.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for [Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html).  You can make the Android act as a Hot Spot / Access Point and then have the PC join the WiFi LAN.  No modem is required.  The example shows how to discover IP addresses of peers.  After that the two devices communicate using sockets and stuff...  Also look at the two sample apps included in your Android SDK at ...\samples\android-19\legacy\WiFiDirect*

Comment: how about java side ? no different from client-server way ? find server and how find IP ?

Comment: There are 2 steps: first you need to somehow establish connectivity (by creating the P2P LAN) and next one side needs to initiate a connection to the other.  The Android samples shows how to find the IP address of the peer.  Most of the work to set up the WiFi LAN gets done on the Android.  The PC side can be a simple "server" that waits for an incoming connection on a known port and accepts it.